# Автозагрузчик файлов Yii

Tags: php-frameworks, php, yii

привет.
Начал просматривать фреймоворк Yii.
Мне стало не понятно где автозагрузчик файлов Yii?(думал при установке может идет добаление include_path.Вроде php.ini не изменился.)
Проблемный участок кода:

```
class Yii extends YiiBase{}

сlass YiiBase{
    public static function createWebApplication($config=null)
    {
        return self::createApplication('CWebApplication',$config);
    }
}
Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

Теперь мне непонятно как идет поиск класса CWebApplication ?

Comment: Не претендует на статус полного ответа, скорее просто подсказка: Там где-то внутри самого Yii зашит большой массив с сопоставлением строковых названий классов с файлами, которые нужно инклудить при попытке создания экземпляра этого класса. Могу ошибаться, давно это уже было, точно уже не помню.

Comment: Теперь попытаюсь найти его...Наверно это /config/main.php.

 'import'=>array(
  'application.models.*',
  'application.components.*',
 ),

   еще пока не разобрался как идет подключение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно [вот это](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/YiiBase.php#L392) и есть автозагрузчик.

Comment: Буду разбиратся..Ьлагодарен.Подскажите если в классе есть метод autoload то он будет запускатся если внутри данного класса вызывается неопределенный класс?Я знаком только с глобальной функцией __autoload() и spl_autoload_register

Comment: Это не подскажу, сам с php мало работал тонкостей не знаю. spl_autoload_register есть в том же файле в предпоследней строке. Но как оно всё работает я пока сам не понял =)

Comment: Он будет вызываться только в том случае, если вы его сами добавите в список функций-автолоадеров